# Usage of MemoryStack in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm just starting to learn OpenGL through LWJGL. Now, I'm storing some vertex data into the VBO. However, there are many different ways of doing this, and I don't know which one should be used.

I've been using it like this so far:

```java
float[] vertices = ...;
int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
// Bind the vbo
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
// Send the data to GPU memory
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The code above works as is. However, I've looked through the [LWJGL wiki](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.3.-Memory-FAQ), and it's saying always use MemoryStack when possible.

Last paragraph in the wiki says:

> 1. Use org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack and if not possible...
> 2. Use org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil and if not possible...
> 3. Use org.lwjgl.BufferUtil

Does that mean the correct way of doing it is something like the following:

```java
try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
    IntBuffer ip = stack.callocInt(1);
    GL15.glGenBuffers(ip);
    int vboID = ip.get(0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

    FloatBuffer buffer = stack.callocFloat(vertices.length);
    buffer.put(vertices);
    buffer.flip();

    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Is the second approach better/more efficient than the first?

Comment: @httpdigest I see. That means I should just stop using on-heap Java if possible?